# Error "RECIPIENTS_NOT_PROVIDED" when recipients provided

Tags: rest, docusignapi

I'm getting the error "RECIPIENTS_NOT_PROVIDED" when using this code block below; from what I can see on the [REST API Explorer](https://apiexplorer.docusign.com/#/esign/restapi?categories=Envelopes&tags=Envelopes&operations=create&mode=basichttp://), my code is correct. Is there anything I have missed??

I'm sure it's something basic, but I just can't see it ...

```
{
   "documents":[
      {
         "documentBase64":"<Base64BytesHere>",
         "documentId":"1",
         "fileExtension":"pdf",
         "name":"Doc1.pdf",
         "order":"1"
      },
      {
         "documentBase64":"<Base64BytesHere>",
         "documentId":"2",
         "fileExtension":"pdf",
         "name":"Doc2.pdf",
         "order":"2"
      },
      {
         "documentBase64":"<Base64BytesHere>",
         "documentId":"3",
         "fileExtension":"pdf",
         "name":"Doc3.pdf",
         "order":"3"
      },
      {
         "documentBase64":"<Base64BytesHere>",
         "documentId":"4",
         "fileExtension":"pdf",
         "name":"Doc4.pdf",
         "order":"4"
      }
   ],
   "emailSubject":"Important announcement from us",
   "carbonCopies":[
      {
         "recipientId":"1",
         "email":"test3@test.com",
         "name":"Test3"
      }
   ],
   "signers":[
      {
         "recipientId":"2",
         "name":"Test1",
         "email":"test1@test.com",
         "tabs":{
            "signHereTabs":[
               {
                  "documentId":"1",
                  "pageNumber":"1",
                  "xPosition":"20",
                  "yPosition":"500"
               },
               {
                  "documentId":"2",
                  "pageNumber":"1",
                  "xPosition":"20",
                  "yPosition":"500"
               },
               {
                  "documentId":"4",
                  "pageNumber":"1",
                  "xPosition":"20",
                  "yPosition":"500"
               }
            ]
         }
      },
      {
         "recipientId":"3",
         "name":"Test2",
         "email":"test2@test.com",
         "tabs":{
            "signHereTabs":[
               {
                  "documentId":"1",
                  "pageNumber":"1",
                  "xPosition":"20",
                  "yPosition":"500"
               },
               {
                  "documentId":"4",
                  "pageNumber":"1",
                  "xPosition":"20",
                  "yPosition":"500"
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   ],
   "status":"sent"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the carbonCopies/signers under "**recipients**" property

```
{
    "documents": [

    ],
    "recipients": {
        "carbonCopies": [

        ],
        "signers": [

        ]
    },
    "emailSubject": "Important announcement from us",
    "status": "sent"
}
```